# windows chrome refresh tab 0(or current tab) via command line

Tags: python, windows, google-chrome, batch-file, python-webbrowser

I'm trying to do it with `python`, `webbrowser` module. But it does not have `Chromium`-specific functions. Is there another way? probably with a batch script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this myself: (I wrote is quickly as it was only for personal use). With a lot of clean up you might be able to get what you want. See https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import os
import subprocess
import json

from websocket import create_connection

def refresh_page(url):
    data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen('http://localhost:9222/json'))

    found_page = False
    for page in data:
        if page['url'].lower() == url.lower():
            found_page = True
            websocketURL = page['webSocketDebuggerUrl']
            ws = create_connection(websocketURL)

            obj = {  "id": 0,
                     "method": "Page.reload",
                     "params":
                     {
                       "ignoreCache": True,
                       "scriptToEvaluateOnLoad": ""
                     }
                  }

            dev_request = json.dumps(obj)
            ws.send(dev_request)
            result =  ws.recv()
            ws.close()
    if not found_page:
        raise Exception("No pageFound")

def open_or_refresh(file_name):
    file_name = "".join ( [f if f in r'\/:*?"<>|' else  urllib.quote(f) for f in file_name] )
    file_name = 'file:///' + file_name.replace('\\', '/')
    file_name = file_name.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    try:
        refresh_page(file_name)
    except:
        cmd = (r'"%(LOCALAPPDATA)s\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"'%os.environ
               + r' --remote-debugging-port=9222  "%s"' % file_name)
        subprocess.Popen(cmd)

open_or_refresh(r"C:\test.html")
open_or_refresh(r"C:\test.html")
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's going wrong maybe another question (A pound is going in a swear jar but all I can say is that it works for me.)

Comment: I got the same error myself if I changed open_or_refresh(r"C:\test.html") to `open_or_refresh(u"C:\\test.html")` you need the string to be in ascii.

Comment: Adding `file_name = file_name.encode('ascii', 'ignore')` should fix your problem.